# ChartJS / MomentJS - Unable to remove deprecation warning. Graph not showing in firefox/opera

Tags: charts, cross-browser, momentjs, chart.js, deprecation-warning

so browsers throw

warning about using momentJS incorrectly.

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 12.30, _f: false, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
```

So i looked at my code

```
data: {
  labels: ['01.01', '02.01', '03.01', '04.01', '05.01', '06.01', '07.01', '08.01', '09.01', '10.01', '11.01', '12.01'],
  datasets: createChatterData(data, this)
},
```

And read that I should provide a format when dealing with non iso strings.

```
labels: [moment('01.01', 'MM.DD'), moment('02.01', 'MM.DD'), ...];
```

Ok that removed first deprecation.

But my datasets data also contains of date

```
    dataset.data.pushObject({
        x: moment(datum).format('MM.DD'),
        y: parseInt(moment(datum).format('YYYY'))
    });
```

So I tried different variations to that (premodified ambigious datetime)

```
x: moment(date, 'YYYY.MM.DD').format('MM.DD')
```

and

```
x: moment(date, 'MM.DD')
```

But my graph doesnt map correctly anymore.

Example of **codepen** chart working in chrome: http://codepen.io/kristjanrein/pen/wJrQLE
Does not display in firefox/opera

Comment: Not sure if you already saw my original answer, but I did just update it and added in another section at the bottom.  I just wanted to let you know so that you did not miss it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a couple of issues here.

1) Since you want your X axis to be a time scale, then you should leave your X data value as a `moment` object.  Your current implementation is creating a `moment` object from a date string and then formatting it back to a string.  When you do this, chart.js then takes the string and tries to create a `moment` object internally when it builds the chart.

Therefore, It is best to keep the data as either a `Date` or `Moment` object and use the time scale configuration properties to determine how the data is displayed on the chart.  This prevents chart.js from having to construct the `moment` object and guess at the string format.

2) You are using the pre-2.0 way to create a chart when you use `Chart.Scatter`.  Instead you should use the new style (`new Chart()`) and pass in a `type` property.

Here is a modified version of you code that results in no browser warnings and works in Chrome and Firefox (I did not test in Opera).

```
var getData = function() {
  var dummyDataset = [
    '2007-11-09T00:00:00.000Z',
    '2006-08-04T00:00:00.000Z',
    '2006-08-06T00:00:00.000Z',
    '2008-01-10T00:00:00.000Z'
  ];

  return dummyDataset.map(function(datum) {
    var myMoment = moment(datum);

    return {
      x: myMoment,
      y: parseInt(myMoment.format('YYYY')),
    };
  });
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart1").getContext("2d");
var myScatter = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
      showLine: false,
      data: getData()
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Random Data'
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        fontSize: 10,
        boxWidth: 20
      }
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        pointStyle: 'rect'
      }
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        position: 'bottom',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Months'
        },
        time: {
          unit: 'month',
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MM'
          },
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [ {
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
          min: 2005,
          max: 2015,
          stepSize: 1
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Year'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

You can see it in action at this [forked codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/wJOOYG).

One other thing to keep in mind is that because your data spans multiple years, you will see duplicate months on the X axis.  Remember, a time scale is used to plot dates so even if you only display the months, a data point with the same month but with different years will not be plotted at the same location.

If you are actually only wanting to show month string/number values in the X axis, then you should not use the `time` scale at all and use the `linear` scale instead.  Then when you build your data values, you would extract the month from the data (the same way you are already doing for your Y value).

```
var getData = function() {
  var dummyDataset = [
    '2007-11-09T00:00:00.000Z',
    '2006-08-04T00:00:00.000Z',
    '2006-08-06T00:00:00.000Z',
    '2008-01-10T00:00:00.000Z'
  ];

  return dummyDataset.map(function(datum) {
    var myMoment = moment(datum);

    return {
      x: parseInt(myMoment.format('MM')),
      y: parseInt(myMoment.format('YYYY')),
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks again! I also added my own modifications below for linear values to work correctly:P cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So in addition to jordan's answer 
I changed my labels and x axis from

```
['01.01', '02.01', ...] to [1,2,...]
```

and

from type: `'time' to type: 'linear'`

And to make it map not only by month but also by day. I had to make date objects to correct floats. 05.20 to 5.66

```
const date = datum.key;
const day = parseInt(moment(date).format('DD')) / 30 * 100;
const fullDate = parseFloat(moment(date).format('MM') + '.' + Math.round(day))
// 05.10 would be 5.3 (10 of 30 is 33%)
{
   x: fullDate, 
   y: parseInt(moment(date).format('YYYY')) 
   date: date, // for tooltip
   count: count  // for tooltip
 }
```

And i also had to make corrections to my tooltips

```
 callbacks: {
   title: function([tooltipItem], data) {
     const tooltipInfo = getTooltip(tooltipItem, data.datasets);

     return tooltipInfo.date;
   },

   label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
     const tooltipInfo = getTooltip(tooltipItem, data.datasets);

     return i18n.t('chart.count') + ': ' + tooltipInfo.count;
   },
 }
```

corresponding tooltip dataset

```
function getTooltip(tooltipItem, datasets) {
    return datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data.find(datum => {
        return datum.x === tooltipItem.xLabel && datum.y === tooltipItem.yLabel;
    });
}
```